# Razor restricts nested sections on a blank file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently in the middle of an automated conversion to MVC 3 Razor.

I have a completely empty view (index.cshtml).

No text or anything.

I try to build it and I see only these errors:

> Error 20  Section blocks ("@section Header { ... }") cannot be nested. 
>   Only one level of section blocks are
>   allowed.  C:\Areas\Administration\Views\AutoTagEvaluation\index.cshtml    147 GideonWeb

I've tried setting Layout to null, but that doesn't fix it.

I don't understand how there can be an error on line 147 in an empty file either.

Is there some external file that's causing the problem? Where could it be?

Wouldn't it have to be explicitly referenced? Or no?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Excluded the file from the project and added the older index.aspx file back in.

Still got the error and it explicitly mentions the dropped index.cshtml file :(

**EDIT EDIT:**

Unloaded project file and made sure it is not referenced anywhere. Still get the error referencing the ghost file.

Comment: Views are not processed at compile time. This error has got to be coming from some other third-party validation that's hooking into the build. Perhaps something like Web Essentials, StyleCop, not sure. Often these run only on files that are actually open in your editor. Close all document tabs and then try to build again and see what happens.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I just installed VS on a new machine, so I don't know how it could be a 3rd party entity. Closing documents, restarting VS, etc. didn't get me past this error :(

Comment: And this is happening during build? This isn't an error you see in the browser when trying to view your site, right?

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Right. It's in VS, not in the browser. I'll post a picture. Btw: I unloaded the proj file, and it didn't have any references to this file.

Comment: I wonder if this could somehow be related to not having a _Layout or a _ViewStart file ..?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm still going back to my original statement here. Views are not compiled, so you should absolutely never get any build errors from a view with just a stock VS install. There's got to be something else in play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that Visual Studio 2010 project files get corrupted easily and that it was time for me to torch my source code and clone from the repo.

Some of the reading around here suggests devs have gotten mileage by renaming .aspx files as .cshtml files.

**UPDATE:**

The view compiler also recurses through files not in the solution explorer and will get picked up if they are .cshtml or .aspx. This might have been what was going on.